# RefToolbar 2.0 generates empty template in references section

Tags: mediawiki

I ported the RefToolbar 2.0 gadget from Wikipedia to my own MediaWiki installation (using [Wikipedia's instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:RefToolbar/2.0#Porting_to_another_wiki)) and the toolbar works fine. But when creating a reference using a template, it just shows a redlink to a template where the reference should be shown in the references section of the article.

Is there something that I missed when porting the gadget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by going to [Special:Export on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Special:Export) and exporting the following templates with the "include templates" checkbox checked:

- Template:cite web
- Template:cite news
- Template:cite book
- Template:cite journal

I then used the [Special:Import](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps#Using_Special:Import) page on my wiki to import the .xml file output by Wikipedia's export page and it all worked fine.

**Note:** You will need to install the [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) extension in order for the imported templates to work.